# Collapsing toolbar title overlaps with my menu icons

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am using the collapsing Toolbar in a project that I am working on currently. I am setting the title of the collapsing toolbar from my code but the problem is if the title is too big then it overlaps with my menu icons in the toolbar. So how can I fix this issue?

Title OverLaps with menu Icon:
[image: Title OverLaps with menu Icon]

My xml code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="205dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/agent_profile_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="87dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="130dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/expandedappbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="170dp"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/back" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="170dp"
                    android:background="#66000000">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lbl_agent_profile_position"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/lbl_agent_profile_Name"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:text="Real Estate Professional at Exit Alliance Realty"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:typeface="sans" />


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lbl_agent_profile_ibaaxid"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="#33ffffff"
                            android:paddingBottom="1dp"
                            android:paddingEnd="3dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                            android:paddingRight="3dp"
                            android:paddingStart="3dp"
                            android:paddingTop="1dp"
                            android:text="iBaax ID : 123456789"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:typeface="sans" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lnr_img"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_agent_profile_image"
                        android:layout_width="110dp"
                        android:layout_height="110dp"

                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/no_profile" />
                </LinearLayout>


                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="22dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lnr_img"
                    android:background="#4d6088"
                    android:paddingEnd="3dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                    android:paddingRight="3dp"
                    android:paddingStart="3dp"
                    android:text="Write Review"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

And the code in my activity's OnCreate Method:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_agent_profile2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    //getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Name");
    agent = (Agent) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Agent");
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
            (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.agent_profile_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(agent.name);
```

Comment: for ellipsize to work try giving fixed width to title textview

Comment: There is no textview for my title. I am setting it from directly from my code with collapsetoolbar.setTitle("");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it somehow. I don't why it work though. I had to give separate styles for expandedTitle and collapseTitle with different textSizes. If they were the same textSizes then it would work. Here are my styles below,

```
<style name="expandedappbar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:width">100dp</item>
</style>
<style name="collapseappbar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

and the layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/agent_profile_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="87dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="130dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/expandedappbar"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/collapseappbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
```

And screenshot to prove that it works,

[image: Fixed]

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Support lib version is `25.2.0`

Answer (score 1):

Please add option menu for menu items, overlapping issue will not be there

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);
    return true; 
}
```

And set `actionBar` in activity `onCreate`:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

`option_menu.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
 
    <item
        android:id="@+id/bt_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_send"
        android:title="@string/share"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/bt_suggest_edit"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu"
        android:title="@string/suggest_an_edit"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Collapsed toolbar screenshot

[image: Collapsed toolbar screenshot]

Expanded toolbar screenshot

[image: Expanded toolbar screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work ?

> getSupportActionBar().setTitle("LongTitle");

Comment: No, it doesn't. The title completely disappears.

Comment: You need to set the title on the CollapsingAppBar, not on the Toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is listen collapsing progress of `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. When it totally collapse I disable title of `AppBarLayout` and set it to activity:

```
@Override
public void onAppBarOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int offset) {
    boolean collapsed = offset == appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(!collapsed);
    getActivity().setTitle(collapsed ? title : null);
}
```